# Display zero value in place of null in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running a SBS 2008 with SQL Server 2008 R2

MYOB EXONET SQL Database

I am trying to find out how much our top customers are spending per month but the below query will not return a zero value if the customer has not spent, I imagine that it does not give me a zero result as there is nothing to add up in the database, however I still need it to produce a zero result as otherwise I can't find out which customers are not spending.

```
SELECT 
    DR.ACCNO, 
    SUM(Analytics_SaleInvoice.SalesValueTaxExclusive)
FROM 
    DR_ACCS DR 
INNER JOIN 
    Analytics_SaleInvoice Analytics_SaleInvoice ON (Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis = DR.ACCNO)
WHERE 
    (DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y')
    AND (Analytics_SaleInvoice.AgePeriod = 5) 
GROUP BY 
    DR.ACCNO, DR.ACCNO,Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis
```

Does anyone have any idea how I can get a zero result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `left outer join` so you get all customers:

```
SELECT DR.ACCNO,
       COALESCE(SUM(Analytics_SaleInvoice.SalesValueTaxExclusive), 0) as Total
FROM DR_ACCS DR LEFT OUTER JOIN
     Analytics_SaleInvoice Analytics_SaleInvoice  
     ON Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis = DR.ACCNO AND
        Analytics_SaleInvoice.AgePeriod = 5
WHERE DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y' 
GROUP BY DR.ACCNO, DR.ACCNO,Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis
ORDER BY COALESCE(SUM(Analytics_SaleInvoice.SalesValueTaxExclusive), 0) DESC;
```

Along with the `left outer join`, the condition on the second table needs to be moved to the `on` clause and the `coalesce()` is used to turn the `NULL` value into a `0`.

I also added an `order by` because you seem to want the best customers first.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT 
    DR.ACCNO, 
    ISNULL(SUM(Analytics_SaleInvoice.SalesValueTaxExclusive), 0)
FROM DR_ACCS DR 
LEFT JOIN Analytics_SaleInvoice Analytics_SaleInvoice  
    ON (Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis = DR.ACCNO)
    AND (Analytics_SaleInvoice.AgePeriod = 5) 
WHERE (DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y')
GROUP BY DR.ACCNO, DR.ACCNO,Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis
```

Comment: Try again - I added an `ISNULL` to turn the null value into 0.

Answer (score 0):

Use a LEFT JOIN between DR_ACCS and Analytics_SalesInvoice instead of an INNER JOIN.  A LEFT JOIN is guaranteed to at least return one result for each record in DR_ACCS.  Something like this should work:

```
SELECT DR.ACCNO, IsNull( SUM(Analytics_SaleInvoice.SalesValueTaxExclusive), 0)
FROM DR_ACCS DR LEFT JOIN Analytics_SaleInvoice Analytics_SaleInvoice  
ON (Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis = DR.ACCNO)
WHERE (DR.X_TOPCUSTOMER = 'Y')
AND ( (Analytics_SaleInvoice.AgePeriod = 5)  OR (Analytics_SalesInvoice.AgePeriod IS NULL) )
GROUP BY DR.ACCNO, DR.ACCNO,Analytics_SaleInvoice.AccountNumberAnalysis
```

Comment: Thanks, this query gives me an error "The multi-part identifier "Analytics_SalesInvoice.AgePeriod" could not be bound." It seems to be "OR (Analytics_SalesInvoice.AgePeriod IS NULL" which is the problem.